# Finishing tab missing in print dialog

Tags: 12.10, printing, laserjet

We have a HP LaserJet 600 M602 Network printer that also includes a stapler, to immediately staple printed documents. In 12.04 in the print dialog there was a "finishing" tab where I could choose that the document should be stapled. However in 12.10 this tab is missing, even though the stapler is listed as "installed" under the installable options.

I have tried to install the printer as a HP JetDirect printer as well as a IPP printer, but it makes absolutely no difference.

Why do I not get the option to use the stapler, even though it is selected as installed?